# QuantLib: BondFunctions.zSpread does not match clean price "exactly"

Tags: quantlib

I am using QuantLib to compute prices of fixed rate bonds in different scenarios. In the first step I would like to replicate the current market price by adjusting the yield curve with the zspread. Using the function BondFunctions.zSpread I get close (in the example below (97.85 versus a market price of 98) but I am wondering why we do not converge to the exact same price when altering the spread continuously. Am I missing something?

The following code adapts [Simple QuantLib Bond Math](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/32539)

```
import pytest
import QuantLib as ql

from QuantLib import *

# Construct yield curve
calc_date = Date(1, 1, 2017)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

spot_dates = [Date(1,1,2017), Date(1,1,2018), Date(1,1,2027)]
# corrected!
# spot_rates = [0.0, 0.04, 0.04]
spot_rates = [0.04, 0.04, 0.04]

day_count = SimpleDayCounter()
calendar = NullCalendar()
interpolation = Linear()
compounding = Compounded
# corrected!
compounding_frequency = Annual
compounding_frequency = Semiannual
spot_curve = ZeroCurve(spot_dates, spot_rates, day_count, calendar,
                       interpolation, compounding,
                       compounding_frequency)

spot_curve_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

# Construct bond schedule
issue_date = Date(1, 1, 2017)
maturity_date = Date(1, 1, 2022)
tenor = Period(Semiannual)
calendar = NullCalendar()
business_convention = Unadjusted
date_generation = DateGeneration.Backward
month_end = False

schedule = Schedule(issue_date, maturity_date, tenor, calendar,
                    business_convention, business_convention,
                    date_generation, month_end)

# Create FixedRateBond Object

coupon_rate = 0.05
coupons = [coupon_rate]
settlement_days = 0
face_value = 100

fixed_rate_bond = FixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                            face_value,
                            schedule,
                            coupons,
                            day_count)

# Set Valuation engine
bond_engine = DiscountingBondEngine(spot_curve_handle)
fixed_rate_bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)

# Calculate present value
value = fixed_rate_bond.NPV()
assert value == pytest.approx(104.49, abs=1.e-2)


# fix a hypothetical market price
px = 98.

# compute the implied z spread
zspread = ql.BondFunctions.zSpread(fixed_rate_bond,
                                   px,
                                   spot_curve, day_count, compounding,
                                   compounding_frequency, calc_date, 1.e-16, 1000000, 0.)


def impl_clean_price(spread):
    spread1 = ql.SimpleQuote(spread)
    spread_handle1 = ql.QuoteHandle(spread1)
    ts_spreaded1 = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(spot_curve_handle,
                                                spread_handle1)
    ts_spreaded_handle1 = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ts_spreaded1)
    ycsin = ts_spreaded_handle1
    fixed_rate_bond = FixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                                    face_value,
                                    schedule,
                                    coupons,
                                    day_count)
    # Set Valuation engine
    bond_engine = DiscountingBondEngine(ycsin)
    fixed_rate_bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)
    value = fixed_rate_bond.cleanPrice()
    return value

# the two clean prices are 98 and 97.8517891975
print px
print impl_clean_price(zspread)
print abs(px-impl_clean_price(zspread))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't supply the compounding convention to `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` explicitly, it will consider the passed spread as continuously compounded and apply it to the base curve accordingly.

You'll need to instantiate the curve instead as:

```
    ts_spreaded1 = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(spot_curve_handle,
                                                spread_handle1,
                                                compounding,
                                                compounding_frequency)
```

This will tell the `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` how to interpret the spread quote and will result in the correct bond price.